# Excel não consegue localizar planilha

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou com um problema muito estranho: fiz um programa usando WinForms em C#, e este programa manipula dados de uma planilha excel. Esta planilha fica salva na rede da empresa, à qual todos temos acesso.

Ao testar o programa no meu computador e em outros 5 computadores, todos funcionam corretamente (isto é, o programa escreve e lê os dados da planilha; ele *localiza e abre* a planilha normalmente), com exceção de um.

Este computador, de uma usuária, ao tentar abrir a planilha, retorna o seguinte erro:

> Não foi possível encontrar "S:...". É possível que ele tenha sido movido, renomeado ou excluído?

O engraçado é: quem criou a pasta em que o arquivo excel está foi a própria usuária! Ela consegue abrir o excel pelo File Explorer, mas quando ele é aberto pelo meu programa, o excel acusa não conseguir localizar o arquivo. E isso acontece **somente** com essa usuária.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: O `S:\` dela está mapeando um diretório de rede diferente dos demais?

Comment: Não... verifiquei agora. Problema solucionado hehe posta isso como resposta, para eu aceitar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique em que diretório está mapeado o `S:\` dela.